# Getting an item from array is changing array itself in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array with couple items in my Angular project. When I get an item from this array, it changes array like this:

```
export interface PersonModel {
    id: number;
    fullName: string;
    birthDate: Date;
    createdOn: Date;
}

people: PersonModel[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.peopleService.getPeople().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(x => {
        this.people = x;
    });
}
```

My people array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "John Doe",
        "birthDate": 1988-01-01,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "fullName": "Jane Doe",
        "birthDate": 1988-06-11,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "fullName": "Xae Doe",
        "birthDate": 1998-02-13,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    }
]

getPerson(id: number) {
    let person = this.people.find(x => x.id == id); 
    
    // doing some coding stuff...
}
```

At this point, when I call this find method `this.getPerson(3)`, it changes my people array like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "fullName": "Xae Doe",
        "birthDate": 1998-02-13,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "fullName": "Jane Doe",
        "birthDate": 1988-06-11,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "fullName": "Xae Doe",
        "birthDate": 1998-02-13,
        "createdOn": 2022-04-19
    }
]
```

I've debugged the code and I am sure `.find` line is causing the problem, but I don't know why.

Comment: I think the `// doing some coding stuff...` is likely the key to your issue. Javascript objects (including arrays) are not immutable, and your observable returns pointer to the array, which contains pointers to the persons. If you updated the array, or the person in the array, it will be updated in the "hidden" array in your service.

Comment: Please add ```//doing some coding stuff``` => as in the actual code, else we can't help